# What regEx can I use to Split a string with comma character in C# .net

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to split string using comma. e.g. `name1(M, 06/06/1993), Namit2 (M, 18/05/2000)`.
First I would like to split above string as

1. `name1(M, 06/06/1993)`
2. `Namit2 (M, 18/05/2000)`

after this I would like to split further e.g `name1(M, 06/06/1993)` would split into

1. `name1`
2. `M`
3. `06/06/1993`

**CASE 1: name1(M, 06/06/1995), name2(M, 18/05/2000)**

First split output should be

1. name1(M, 06/06/1995)
2. name2(M, 18/05/2000)

Second split for first item

1.name1
2.M
3.06/06/1995

**case 2:  name1(M, 26/01/2002)**

Might be as above, only one item

**case 3: name1 (M), name 2(F)**

First split

1. name1 (m)
2. name2 (f)

second split for first item

1. name1
2. m

**case 4: Nikesh, Nihar**

First split

1. nikesh
2. nihar

Comment: Do you have the option of storing this as XML instead of this custom format? It would give you a lot more options for dealing with the data, including the ability to split this out in a SQL query directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `Regex.Split` only for the first example, with this regex

```
\s*,(?![^(]*\))\s*
```

that means split on a `,` (with optional whitespace before and ahead). The important part is this negative lookahead `(?![^(]*\))`, it fails if there is a closing round bracket ahead, but no opening before.

**That means in the first step, I split on commas that are NOT within brackets.**

For the second split I use a normal `String.Split` on round brackets an commas with the the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to avoid having an empty entry at the end because of the closing bracket.

For your examples, this gives you what you want:

```
String s1 = "name1(M, 06/06/1995), name2(M, 18/05/2000)";
String s2 = "name1(M, 26/01/2002)";
String s3 = "name1 (M), name 2(F)";
String s4 = "Nikesh, Nihar";

String[] input = { s1, s2, s3,s4 };
String[] Split1 = {};
List<String[]> Result = new List<String[]>();

foreach (String item in input) {
    Console.WriteLine("Splitting: " + item);

    Split1 = Split1.Concat(Regex.Split(item, @"\s*,(?![^(]*\))\s*")).ToArray();
}

foreach (String item in Split1) {
    Console.WriteLine("Splitting: " + item);

    Result.Add(item.Split(new char[]{ '(', ')', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}

foreach (String[] item in Result) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item.Select(v => v.ToString())));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:
`(.+)\),(.+)`
`(.+)\s\((.+),\s(.+)\)`

Comment: That wasn't in the dataset.  You want something that specific, or if there are aberrations in the data, you should show that in your example.  I have no idea what the constraints are, or if it supposed to have already been sanitized when you run the RegEx on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the language of your choice but in Java you can do this:

```
string s1="name1(M, 06/06/1993)";
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(s1, ",\\s*|\\(\\s*|\\s*\\)");
foreach (string token in tokens) {
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[name1, M, 06/06/1993]
```

Comment: its spliting everything into one go, can you give me two syntex, so fist split by comma which is not in bracket and after i would liket to do second split on first item of fist split

Comment: To just split the string by comma use: `Regex.Split(s1, ",');`

Comment: name1 (F, 28/7/1997), name 2(F, 13/05/2002)" which split into 4 items insted of 2 items

Comment: once i have 2 items i would like to split again and get birthdate and gender information about perticular item

Answer (score 0):

I would do a REGEXP_REPLACE functions in Oracle. Something like below

```
REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'name1(M, 06/06/1993), Namit2 (M, 18/05/2000)',
                        '.+\), ') A,
REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'name1(M, 06/06/1993), Namit2 (M, 18/05/2000)',
                        '\), .+', ')') B
```

In the above case A = Namit2 (M, 18/05/2000)
And B= name1(M, 06/06/1993)

You can store A and B in different variables and then run some more regExp on them to split them up.

Comment: So you can either achieve it in SQL while fetching it OR you can do this in C# with string functions its upto you.

Answer (score 0):

This should split each line

```
[^\(|,]+?\(.{13}\)(?=,|\.)
```

This will further split each match

```
\(|,|\)
```

I used RegExBuddy to test this using the .NET regex engine.

### Update

This should split both variations

```
[\w\d\s]+?\([^\)]+\)
```

Comment: first split failed on "Chirayu (M), Charvee (F)". is there any way i can fix it?